# Why is paging not working in the Data View Web Part?

Tags: data-view-web-part, paging, sharepoint-designer

I am unable to make paging work in the Data View Web Part on SharePoint 2010. I selected a paging option in the SharePoint Designer ribbon, but it does nothing. Limiting the number of items, in the same menu, works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: stupid question but are there more items than your page limit in your dataset?

Comment: :-) yes, I did a test with 11 items, and tried to select paging by 5 and paging by 5.
Is paging working fine for you?

Answer (score 1):

I just did a very simple test. I created a Custom List with no additional columns beyond the Title and added 5 items to the list. Then I edited a default.aspx page (this is in my sandbox!) and added a Data View Web Part which simply shows the Title in Multiple Item View. Then I tried setting the paging to 1, 3, 5, all, etc.  Every setting which I've tried works just fine.

I wonder what is different about your situation. What type of list is it? What type of columns are you showing, etc.?

Comment: Thanks Marc, let me try again and see how it goes. I think what I used was a tasks list.

Comment: I just tested with a Tasks list and it works fine as well.